# How to communicate Front End( in C#, HTML, JQuery) with Backend( JAX-RS( Jersey) and JAVA)?

Tags: java, c#, .net, java-8, jax-rs

I want to develop a Web application in which front end will be developed in HTML, C#, ASP.net and server side will be using JAVA ( JAX-RS jersey ).
So, the front end will be running on IIS server and java will be running on Tomcat server.
 How to consume Java REST API from C#?
I mean is there any way to to communicate between two different servers ?

Note: This is my second time asking question on this platform, so I am sorry if my question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "How to consume Java REST API from C#?" The API is ignorant of the language it is implemented in. An example: You want to consume some Google REST API. Do you know in what language they implement the backing services? Do you care?

Comment: Googling "C# how to consume REST API" gave top 2 : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1190592/A-few-great-ways-to-consume-RESTful-API-in-Csharp , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client ... for starters

Comment: "sorry if my question doesn't make any sense." You can always check [ask] ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can look into using the Spring framework. With the Spring framework, you can build a RESTful web service that has end-points with which your front-end can communicate. It works like the C# Web-Api, in that you can define a "base URL" and other specific URLs that you can link to a function in your Java code.

Spring website:

https://spring.io/

Some help to getting started:

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try to do that.

Comment: Spring is not the answer to everything. This question is well answerable without Spring ...

Comment: #Fildor please explain, Is there any better way to achieve that functionality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: True @Fildor. It is only a suggestion. There are of course many answers to this question, and this is the one I choose to give.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. What you gave is not answering the question at all. It is telling the OP to do what he is going to do anyway with a different tool. It says nothing about how to *consume* the API on C# side, which was the actual question.

Comment: The link to the JournalDev has that information.

Comment: @ApexPredator You need to use "@" not "#" to notify a user. But to your question: If Jersey fits your requirements and you feel confident using it, use it. Jersey or Spring - You'll end up with a RESTful WebService.

Comment: "The link to the JournalDev has that information." - No it doesn't. The only example I saw was a Spring Client (== Java). OP explicitly asks for C#.

Comment: Very well. What would you suggest he'd do? I'd love to hear your solution.

Comment: Easy: He should *google* "how to consume RESTful Webservices in C#" - There are plenty of HowTos and Tutorials and whatnot.